# HDFS can't read data (Got error, status message opReadBlock)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have done Haddop upgrade and downgrade operation, and then the old data cannot be opened. Could you please help me to check this problem

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.10.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsRollingUpgrade.html#namenode_-rollingUpgrade

```
[root@master current]# hdfs dfs -cat /test/test.csv
21/03/02 14:42:17 WARN hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.io.IOException: Got error, status message opReadBlock BP-1289313299-192.168.1.26-1533200460191:blk_1073762237_21423 
received exception java.io.IOException: BlockId 1073762237 is not valid., 
for OP_READ_BLOCK, self=/10.10.202.26:47930, remote=/10.10.202.26:50010, 
for file /test/test.csv, for pool BP-1289313299-192.168.1.26-1533200460191 block 1073762237_21423
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.DataTransferProtoUtil.checkBlockOpStatus(DataTransferProtoUtil.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.checkSuccess(RemoteBlockReader2.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:818)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:69
...
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-1289313299-192.168.1.26-1533200460191:blk_1073762237_21423 file=/test/test.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSInputStream.java:983)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:882)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:934)
    at java.io.DataInputStrea

-rw-r--r--   1 root   supergroup        359 2018-08-21 11:19 /test/test.csv


[root@master current]# hdfs fsck /test/
Connecting to namenode via http://master:50070/fsck?ugi=root&path=%2Ftest
FSCK started by root (auth:SIMPLE) from /10.10.202.26 for path /test at Tue Mar 02 15:05:23 CST 2021
...................................................Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    6720241197 B
 Total dirs:    17
 Total files:   51
 Total symlinks:        0
 Total blocks (validated):  85 (avg. block size 79061661 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   85 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:    0
```

The file also failed to download
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDmZT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure time is correct and synced on all servers.
Ensure datanode files have correct permission on linux filesystem.

try:

```
hadoop fsck /test/ -files -blocks
hadoop fsck /test/  -list-corruptfileblocks
```

There is some cases that changing hdfs-site.xml file:

```
<property> 
<name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name> 
<value>true</value> 
</property> ​
```

helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: ![root@master sbin]# hadoop fsck /test/  -list-corruptfileblocks
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Connecting to namenode via http://master:50070/fsck?ugi=root&listcorruptfileblocks=1&path=%2Ftest
The filesystem under path '/test/' has 0 CORRUPT files

Comment: The following one is also configured, but it still doesn't work, I don't know why

Comment: /test/test.csv 359 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
0. BP-1289313299-192.168.1.26-1533200460191:blk_1073762237_21423 len=359 repl=1